# Unity ui mask not working on google pixel device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr, daydream

I am making a scrolling ui panel and apply mask to ScrollRect component, which should hides parts outside panel area. I am using unity version 5.4.2f2-GVR. Mask work correctly on pc when i deploy it on google pixel device its not working. Is this bug of unity version or something else....

[image]

Comment: Do you have another child mask that disabled?

Comment: No. I add mask only on parent that has ScrollRect component attached.

Comment: Try Bijan's solution. If that does not work, got to Help->Report a Bug... then file a bug report. This question has been asked more than 2x within the last 2 weeks so I believe this is a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got around this issue by using `RectMask2D` Component instead of the regular `Mask`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If somebody else got this problem and **Bahman_Aries solution** is not enough, try this:

File > Build Settings > Player Settings>XR Settings (or Other settings if you are working in older versions of unity) > Daydream (click on the small arrow) > Depth Format.

And set that to **24-bit depth | 8-bit stencil**.

This is cause you need a stencil buffer.

Answer (score 2):

`ScrollRect` component has this weird behaviour when an image in its `content` has its material set to something other than `none`.

Unset the material to `None` and it should work.

[image]

---

If every child of content already has no material, then it could be a bug.

Comment: There is no material attched to its image content.

Comment: @vishal you mean those white rectangles has no material?

Comment: No. I make image content source to None and fill with white color.

Comment: @vishal no? I added a photo, this is what I mean.