# Unity 5 Mask not working on Google Pixel phone with Google VR SDK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-vr

I have a Mask component applied to a Panel within an Canvas. The mask is using a sprite to achieve the rounded corners. Everything looks good in the editor, but when I deploy to my Google Pixel phone the mask is ignored.

[You can see the issue HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MQnh.jpg)

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426351/unity-ui-mask-not-working-on-google-pixel-device), but the solution to apply a Rect2d mask doesn't allow for a custom sprite and thus no rounded corners.

I also tried toggling the "Disable Depth and Stencil" and "Use 32-bit Display Buffer" open in the Player Settings, but that had no affect.

I'm using Unity 5 Free Edition with the GoogleVR SDK and a Google Pixel phone running the latest version of Android OS, v7.1 (Nougat).

Are there any known issues with masks on Android? Anything I'm missing?

Comment: I have the same problem and I found [this answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/964309/cardboard-related-mask-shader-issue.html) from JBPrime. It's work for me.